# How does Explorer enumerate Windows Search results?

Tags: windows, com, enumeration, explorer, windows-search

I'm trying to understand how Windows Explorer displays Search results.

From my experience (Windows 7), for regular folders (and namespace extensions) it seems to call `IShellFolder->EnumObjects`.

I also know of the `IEnumShellItems` interface.
I did some API monitoring and it doesn't seem like Explorer calls these when displaying Search results.

So how does Explorer enumerate the results? How does Windows Search (I'm guessing `SearchFolder.dll`) provide the results?

Can someone please describe the flow and the interfaces both sides use?